# Google Map: How to redirect to other points in the map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map and a select.
I have to give the user to the select different places in the select and redirect him to that place in the map.

So when a user select place A he can be redirected to San Francisco for example.
And when select place B he can be redirected to Los Angeles.

Do you know how can i obtain this?

Here i made a basic example, there is the map and the selector:

http://jsbin.com/iGOmEXeP/2/edit

Here i made my shy attempt to obtain what i needed, that as you see is not working:

http://jsbin.com/iGOmEXeP/3/edit

Hope that somebody can helps me!
Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I have obtained something here:
http://jsbin.com/iGOmEXeP/5/edit

Anyway if you have something better, or a way to improve it, i will consider as correct answer.

Comment: Your question is not really clear (to me). What is attached to place A and place B values ? coordinates ? You want to put a marker on the selected place and center the map on this marker ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope is more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read up on the documentation here.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

What you are looking for is either the `setCenter()` or `panTo()` methods.

http://jsbin.com/iGOmEXeP/6/edit

Update your bin to include it like so:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);

  if($this.val() === "1") {
   pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-24.397, 150.644);
  } else if($this.val() === "2") {
    pos = new google.maps.LatLng(-44.397, 150.644);
  } 
  map.panTo(pos);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Smeegs.
From what i have read on the documentation the panTo include a default animation: if the change is less than both the width and height of the map, the transition will be smoothly animated.

That's why you have choosen it instead of setCenter() ?

Comment: Exactly, I think it provides a nice transition when available.

Comment: Yes, definitely better.
http://jsbin.com/iGOmEXeP/7/edit
Here is possible to comment out one or the other option and panTo works much more smoothly than setCenter.